# Regcomp alternative for matching patterns in non-ASCII stream

Tags: c, regex, linux, unicode, gnu

so far , I have been using in my programs `regcomp` to use regular expressions on regular strings.

Now, I need to find particular byte patterns in non-ASCII binary streams: it is my understanding that `regcomp` cannot work in this context.

Practically, I would like something that lets me define - let's say - a 3-byte pattern, possibly using hex notation:

```
\x27\x87\xFE
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a regex library that works on UTF-8, you should use [Phillip Hazel’s excellent *PCRE library*](http://www.pcre.org/).

Comment: @ziu I didn’t know that the regular regcomp(3) disallowed 8-bit codes then.  Do they really? I never heard of such a restriction. It’s a POSIX function (IEEE Std 1003.2), so should work with 8-bit locales. What exactly is the problem? Notation?

Comment: my problem is that I tried to make regcomp work with non-printable bytes - i.e. arbitrary byte values outside the ASCII range - but I cannot get it to match my patterns.

Comment: @ziu I would check the source code. regcomp shouldn’t care about printability at all.

Answer (score 0):

What I discovered in short:

- regexp.h does not interpret the input strings. This means:
  you can easily pass arbitrary bytes to `regcomp` like this

  char buffer[10]="\x01abcd\x03";

  But when it comes to pass the same string above encoded in ASCII, regexp.h will not interpret it as the C compiler does.
- PCRE is nicer to work with when parsing network stuff. Thanks [tchrist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/471272/tchrist)